# Global raw escaping in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is it possible to set a directive that every variable in a Twig template within a certain scope will be escaped with the [raw filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html)?

Ex.

```
{% setAllRaw %}

    {{foo}} // this will be rendered as if foo|raw
    {{bar}} // this will be rendered as if bar|raw
    {{baz}} // this will be rendered as if baz|raw

{% endSetAllRaw %}
```

Instead of having to explicitly write

```
    {{foo|raw}} 
    {{bar|raw}}
    {{baz|raw}}
```

It would be great if this was inherited by child templates..

```
{% setAllRaw %}

    {{foo}} // this will be rendered as if foo|raw
    {% include 'component.twig' %} // every variable in this template will also be rendered as raw

{% endSetAllRaw %}
```

** AND/OR **

Is there a way to indicate in the controller that a variable is to be rendered as raw

Ex.

```
// Controller

$data['foo'] = renderAsRaw($foo);

return new Response($this->renderView('template.html.twig', $data));

// Template

{{foo}} // will be rendered as raw
```

I tried using the [autoescape](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/autoescape.html) but this does not work as I have described above

```
{% autoescape %}
    {{foo}} // this does NOT render as raw
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: If you want to mark data safe from inside the controller you could use the `Twig_Markup` class e.g. `return new \Twig_Markup($html , 'UTF-8');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your templates by default use autoescaping.

You can disable `autoescape` for part of your template by adding `false` in `autoescape` block declaration:

```
{% autoescape false %}
    {{ rawVar }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

If you need to disable autoescaping in all your templates you can set global parameter in config.yml:

```
twig:
    autoescape: false
```

Comment: this did it! thank you! I also needed to set `strict_variables` in config/twig.yml (or config.yml in earlier versions) to `false` to turn off autoescaping for templates included within another template